# This tag is [never] useful

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking around in the [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page on Stack Overflow, and I found this strange little tag called [never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/never). What's the point of this tag? It doesn't have a tag wiki, and there're [no questions tagged under it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/never) Is this tag even related to programming? As I see it, we'll [never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/never) need the [never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/never) tag. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there are no questions posted under the tag, the tag will automatically disappear overnight.
There's no need to put in a [burniate-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burniate-request).